# Convergence properties of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ be two sequence of positive numbers such that

(1) $\lim_{n}a_{n}=0$.

(2) $\sum_{n\geq 1}b_{n}<\infty$ .

(3) $a_{n+1}<a_{n}+b_{n}$ for each $n\geq 1$.

From (2) and (3), we have $\lim_{n}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\leq 1$ whenever $b_{k}/a_{k}\longrightarrow 0$. Can we derive some others  "convergence property" of the sequence $a_{n}$?

Many thansk in advance for your comments.

Comment: I don't understand your question. $(1)$ is clearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The properties (1)-(3) are properties of  the sequences, "a priori" not related between them. The question is if twe can derive some (not trivial) convergence property of $a_{n}$.